# Display Post by taxonomy and taxonomy child if exist

Tags: taxonomy

I have a registered  Taxonomy called Types, which is hierarchical and works.
An example of categories will be
Hotel in UK
--1 star
--2 star
--3 star
Hotel in Spain
--1 star
--2 star
--3 star
etc..

I m having trouble finding the right way to display my pages (custom post Hotel).

I need the code to display hotels by taxonomy only if they exist

any help?

UPDATE CODE

```
 $taxonomy2 = 'accomodation-type';
 $termsacc = get_terms("accomodation-type",array('orderby' => 'slug', 'order' => 'ASC'));
   foreach ($termsacc as $termaccomodation) {
   //Here I loop through my tax acc-type
   //and check if there is any post by the country $termcountry->name (getting this value higher)
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'accomodation', 'orderby'=> $termaccomodation->name,'order' => 'DESC','accomodation-type' =>$termaccomodation->name, 'country' =>$termcountry->name,'posts_per_page' => 48 ));
```

and loop....

Answer (score 2):

I would use in this case two custom taxonomies:

- hotel-country
- stars

both none-hierarchical then your query would be as simple as for example hotel in uk with 2 stars:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'hotel',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'hotel-country',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'uk' ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'stars',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( '3-stars' ),
        )
    )
);
$query_posts( $args );
```

### Update:

Using your existing setup you can once again use `'tax_query'` but you will need to now the child-taxonomy id, say:

```
UK
  3-stars - term_id = 32
```

then your query and args should be:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'hotel',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'Types',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array( '32' ),
            'operator' => 'IN',
        )
    )
);
$query_posts( $args );
```

### Update 2:

If you are already in the UK page then change you code to this:

```
$taxonomy2 = 'accomodation-type';
//the current page term id, (UK,JAPAN...)
$current_term_id = get_query_var('term_id');
//array of child terms IDs. 
$termchildren = get_term_children($current_term_id,$taxonomy2); 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'accomodation',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'accomodation-type',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $termchildren,
            'operator' => 'IN',
        )
    )
);
$query( $args );
//loop
```

this will get all posts of accomodation that have a accomodation-type child term of UK.

Comment: thx Ba...trouble is I already have a lot of data entered, and cant really modify my taxonomy. Any idea how I get around if my existing set up?

Comment: Thx again, but the ID is "dynamic". At the moment I am doing $termsacc = get_terms("accomodation-type",array('orderby' => 'slug', 'order' => 'ASC')); then a foreach(). How will retrieve the id inside my loop?

Comment: @salocin: why inside the loop? update your question with your code so i'll get a better look and understanding.

Comment: code added. thx BA. The country is retrieved higher on my page (ie UK), so I check if any post for the custom taxonomy acc-type in the country exist. Ideally I would like the display to do: Accomodation Type 1(ie Hotel), in Region of UK, list accom...

Comment: i still don't understand what your are trying to do? list all posts of accomodation that have the accomodation-type what? UK? UK->1star? UK->2stars? UK->3stars?

Comment: ok sorry...You are on the UK page. I am trying to list ALL typeof accomodation, but only if they exists. So Hotels, We have 2 X 1 star, 3 x 2 star then B&B we have 2 X 1 star etc etc,,,

Comment: Ok, then I updated the answer

Comment: it's not picking up the right country for some reason. when I try to print_r $current_term_id = get_query_var('term_id'); or  $termchildren = get_term_children($current_term_id,$taxonomy2); I am getting an empty array()

Comment: it means that you are not on a taxonomy page, try print_r($wp_query->query_vars); and see what you have there

Comment: I am really confused and i think it's getting complicated for no reasons. frustrating..thx for your help so far

Comment: Need a solution to this, created a follow up question with new code at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12905/display-post-by-taxonomy-and-taxonomy-child