# Display Post by taxonomy and taxonomy child

Tags: taxonomy, query

This is a follow up to [Display Post by taxonomy and taxonomy child if exist](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12812/display-post-by-taxonomy-and-taxonomy-child-if-exist)

I need to display a list of Accomodation, first by Type of Accomodation, then by Regions.
I have a post-type, called `accomodation`, a taxonomy `Country`, a taxonomy `accomodation-type`, a taxonomy `Region`

I am in the Country page, where I retrieve the value of the country via

```
$taxonomy = 'country';
$terms=get_the_terms($post->ID,$taxonomy);

if($terms) {
    foreach( $terms as $termcountry ) {
```

So I am successfully getting `$termcountry->name;` as the value of current country.

Next I need to do my query for the Accomodation based on that country, filtered by Accomodation Type, and by region in this type.
So it should be

- Acc-Type 1

  - Region1

    - Acco 1
    - Acco 2
    - Acco 3
  - Region 2

    - Acco 1
    - Acco 2
- Acc-Type 2
- etc....

I am trying to do it this way

```
$taxonomy2 = 'accomodation-type';
$termsacc = get_terms("accomodation-type",array('orderby' => 'slug', 'order' => 'ASC'));
       //Loop through Acc-Type
        foreach ($termsacc as $termaccomodation) {
            //Loop through Region in this type
            $taxonomyregion = 'region';
            $termsreg = get_terms("region",array('orderby' => 'slug', 'order' => 'ASC'));
             foreach ($termsreg as $termregion) {
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'accomodation',
                'country' => $termcountry->name,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'accomodation-type',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => array($termaccomodation->name),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'region',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => array($termregion->name),
                    )
                )
            );


            $query = new WP_Query($arg); 
             //Do the loop
```

but this is not doing it....
Scratching my head proper on this one and will appreciate some help/solution
thx in advance

Comment: any help please?

Answer (score 1):

You should query all `accomodation` posts in this `country`, and then sort them by `accomodation-type` and `region`. Then you loop through the posts, and compare the accomodation type and the region of each post with those of the previous post. If they are different you print the new accomodation type or region and then print the post.

```
// Pseudo-code to explain the idea
$prev_post_accomodation_type = $accomodations[0]->accomodation_type;
$prev_post_region = $accomodations[0]->region;
echo '<ul>';
echo '<li>' . $prev_post_accomodation_type . '<ul>';
echo '<li>' . $prev_post_region . '<ul>';
foreach ( $accomodations as $accomodation ) {
    $cur_post_accomodation_type = $accomodation->accomodation_type;
    $cur_post_region = $accomodation->region;
    if ( $prev_post_accomodation_type != $cur_post_accomodation_type ) {
        echo '</ul></li>'; // Close previous region list
        echo '</ul></li>'; // Close previous accomodation type list
        echo '<li>' . $cur_post_accomodation_type . '<ul>';
        echo '<li>' . $cur_post_region . '<ul>';
    } elseif ( $prev_post_region != $cur_post_region ) {
        echo '</ul></li>'; // Close previous region list
        echo '<li>' . $cur_post_region . '<ul>';
    }
    echo '<li>' . $accomodation->post_title . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul></li>'; // Close previous region list
echo '</ul></li>'; // Close previous accomodation type list
echo '</ul>';
```

You can do this sorting in the database or in PHP. In PHP could be easier, but will require many extra database queries because you do `get_post_terms()` for each post. In the database is faster but will require some filtering of the SQL query that WordPress will execute.

*My spelling corrector wants to replace `accomodation` with `accommodation`, is it too late to change this in your code too?*

Comment: Hi Jan, Thank you for trying but this got me more confused!. I have to create a new post with new code. I will appreciate some help